# How to get a check_circle icon with a black tick color instead of white in Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here is my code i wanted to show black tick which is inside circle.

```html
<mat-icon 
  [ngStyle]="{ color: selectedColor === color.checkedCircleColor ? 
                color.checkedCircleColor : color.innerCircleColor}"
  >{{ selectedColor === color.checkedCircleColor ?
     'check_circle' : 'circle' }}
</mat-icon>
```

i am trying to add white tick color but its showing white tick color in mat-icon

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this class to your CSS:

```
.black-icon {
    color: black;
}
```

And your layout will be this:

```
<mat-icon [ngClass]="{'black-icon': selectedColor === color.checkedCircleColor}" svgIcon="check_circle"></mat-icon>
```